# Calendar Api Salesforce

Tags: rest

I am trying to create an event on the google calendar using rest api.But getting the permissions error.

```
Http h = new Http();
                    string calendarId='a@b.com';
                    string url='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'+calendarId+'/events';
                    string body='{"end":{"date": "2013-06-21"},"start":{"date": "2013-06-20"}}';
                    HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
                     System.debug('-----accesstokenvvvvvvvv---'+accesstoken);
                    req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+accesstoken);
                    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    req.setEndpoint(url);
                    req.setBody(body);
                    System.debug('-----body---'+body);
                    req.setMethod('POST');
                    HttpResponse res;
                    res = h.send(req);
                    string data=res.getBody();
                    System.debug('--------data----'+data);
```

Here is the response :

```
 {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
        "message": "Insufficient Permission"
       }
      ],
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Insufficient Permission"
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah I got the answer what happend like i was getting the auth code for the google api not for the google calendar that why it gave me the token of not the calendar.So please send the auth code for calendar api.